# Chinese visual studio sln characters translate to English

Tags: visual-studio

I have been studying a C++ project in GitHub that was written in Chinese. When I open the project on my computer, I don't see Chinese or English, but instead I get an incomprehensible sequences of characters.

For example:

```
SetColor(TITLE_COLOR); cout << "\"¡ü\"¡¢\"¡ý\"¼üÑ¡Ôñ£¬»Ø³µ¼üÈ·ÈÏ£¬Esc¼üÍË³ö"; 
SetColor(THEME_COLOR);

//²Î¿¼Ïà¶ÔÎ»ÖÃÉè¶¨
```

Is there a way to translate this to English, or maybe Chinese (so I can then translate it to English)?

Comment: Do you have the link for the source? You might need to manually install some languages and fonts.

Comment: Check the encoding of the file. Most likely it's UTF8 and the editor is trying to interpreting in some other way.

Comment: Just checked, the original file was likely encoded in GB2312

Comment: https://github.com/NJU-TJL/PacManX/blob/master/PacManX/PacManX/Game.cpp

Comment: Link to the source in comment above

Comment: You will need to tell Visual Studio how to open the file. You can do that via the "Open With" dialog and choosing a "With Encoding" editor; as @Ranoiaetep says it will likely be GB2312. There's a chance you will also need to configure the compiler and/or console to use that encoding in order for the characters to show up properly when you run the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a working website that docodes it: http://www.mxcz.net/tools/en-US/DecodeChar.aspx

You can simply paste the entire thing, and select `Chinese(GB2312)` and `Decoding`

After decoding, it would be:

```
SetColor(TITLE_COLOR); cout << "\"↑\"、\"↓\"键选择，回车键确认，Esc键退出"; 
SetColor(THEME_COLOR);

//参考相对位置设定
```

And the first line would loosely translate to:

> using up/down arrow key to select, enter key to confirm, and esc key to quit

And the last line:

> refer to relative position settings

Answer (score 0):

You can reloading or reopen as Chinese(GB2312) in texteditors like EmEditor.

```
SetColor(TITLE_COLOR); cout << "\"↑\"、\"↓\"键选择，回车键确认，Esc键退出"; 
SetColor(THEME_COLOR);

//参考相对位置设定
```